# I need help understanding proofs of Gibbs' Inequality using Jensen's Inequality.

Tags: probability, convex-analysis, information-theory

I've recently begun to study the basics of Information Theory using this pdf: https://web.stanford.edu/~montanar/RESEARCH/BOOK/partA.pdf, and have just read about Kullback-Leiber Divergence; there Gibbs' inequality is proven (although it isn't called by that name) using the convexity of the function: $-\log_2 x$ and Jensen's Inequality; some other proofs use the same idea with other convex functions like $\ x\log_2 x$ .

All well so far except for one thing: The functions that are used in the proofs are not $-\log_2 x$ or $\ x\log_2 x$ , but their composition with other functions like: $-\log_2 \left(\frac{q(x)}{p(x)}\right)$ or $\ \left(\frac{q(x)}{p(x)}\right)\log_2 \left(\frac{q(x)}{p(x)}\right)$ with $q(x)$ and $p(x)$ being probability distributions with $x \in \mathcal I$ such that $\ \forall x \in \mathcal I, \ q(x),p(x) \neq 0$ and $\sum \limits_{x \in \mathcal I} q(x) = 1$ and $\sum \limits_{x \in \mathcal I} p(x) = 1$.

The thing is: How do i know if the new composite functions are convex and so Jensen's Inequality applies? depending on $q(x)$ and $p(x)$, $f(x)=q(x)/p(x)$ may or may not be convex, and may or may not be non-decreasing; and i know examples of compositions of convex functions that are not convex.

I understood another proof that didn't use Jensen's Inequality at all, it's this kind of proofs that i have trouble with.

All help would be appreciated, regarding the question and also regarding style (i'm new so...)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Jensen says that for convex $f$ and random variable $Y$, $\mathbb{E}f(Y)\ge f(\mathbb{E}Y)$
- $f(x)=-\log x$ is convex
- We can let $Y=\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}$. As $X$ is a random variable, $Y$ is also just a random variable.
- Jensen thus says that $\mathbb{E}[-\log Y] \ge -\log\mathbb{E}Y$
- Taking expectations with respect to $q$, this becomes

$$\mathbb{E}\left[-\log \frac{p(X)}{q(X)}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\log \frac{q(X)}{p(X)}\right]=D_{KL}(q||p) \ge -\log\mathbb{E}_q\left(\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}\right)=-\log\mathbb{E}_p(1)=0$$

and thus, Gibbs' inequality is proven.

Comment: $Y$ can be any function? Isn't there a problem if the composite function: $f \circ Y (x)$ isn't convex?

Comment: have edited answer to address this - $Y$ is just a random variable

Comment: Well a random variable is a function =P. It seems my problem comes from a misunderstanding of Jensen's Inequality, i'll have to review the topic. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: you're correct! though in the context of jensen, you typically have one "variable" ($Y$) and one "function" ($f$), so i thought that might be unhelpful/confounding in trying to explain the solution.